# Javascript Service Worker - How to fire an event when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

I am currently experimenting with Service Workers, especially Push Notifications in chrome. The problem is just that I have no idea how to start it.

Following: 
In my index.html I request first of all the notification permission. If the permissions gets granted I register my service worker. When the service worker is ready I am using promise to get the resolve function with the registration as first parameter. Then I am going to show the notifcation

Here the code:

```
<script>
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
    if (result === 'granted') {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
            registration.showNotification('Notification with ServiceWorker', {
                "body": "Test",
                "vibrate": [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 400]
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Now I don't know how to start the sw.js

When I am registering an event I need something that fires my event. When I close my browser I am not able to fire events.

To my question: I have a JSON file. Is it possible to set an event on that file and when the file changes the event fires?

Comment: You need to implement a service worker that has an appropriate `push` event handler, and you need to register it as a client for a push messaging service. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/ has some basics, and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client has details of an implementation that uses the Firebase cloud messaging service as the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get started with a service worker you need to initialize it in your index html. something like this

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', {scope: './'}).then((registration) => {
        console.log('sw registered');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('registration failed');
    });
}
```

this will register `service-worker.js` as your service worker.
More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register).

Next you will have to listen to `push` event something like

```
self.addEventListener('push', ()=>{
    // listen to push notifications here
});
```

For testing purpose, you can use the chrome dev tools [image]

You can click the "push" link in the above pic to emulate a push notification. However to test a case when the browser is closed you will need to setup a working push notification system to send the notification to service worker, while the browser is closed.